# MaxDegreeOfParallelism not limiting the number of parallel tasks

Tags: c#

I am creating a number of threads and want to execute only N at a time. But I have a problem that when the code is executed it starts all threads at once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Global.MyList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start signal from thread", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        var account = Global.MyList[i];
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Debug.WriteLine("End signal from thread", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    });
    thread.Name = i.ToString();
    threads.Add(thread);
}

var option = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(numThreads.Value)
};

var locker = new Object();
Parallel.ForEach(threads, option, t =>
{
    if (t.IsAlive == false)
    {
        t.Start();
    }
    var count = Convert.ToInt32(t.Name);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
    lock (locker)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Number of active threads:" + count);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref count);
});
```

Comment: I know you are probably just debugging/spiking, but generally you want to avoid locking as in `lock()` because it's kinda a _ball-and-chain_ practice that defeats the benefits of contemporary concurrency programming (particularly via TPL).  Old school multithreading was filled with critical sections, mutexs and semaphores which are not only complex but if done wrong can hurt performance.  You want to minimise locking and blocking threads.  There are other ways to accomplish such things and generally invokes re-thinking a design. :)

Comment: Well you are creating the threads yourself, rather than TPL do it for you.  You might want to consider having TPL create the threads for you (during the `Parallel.ForEach` rather than explicitly spinning them up via `new Thread`.  Not to mention you are probably **doubling** up the **number of threads** in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually *starting* the threads `numThreads.Value` at a time, but starting threads is very quick and they will all end up *executing* simultaneously.

If your goal is to to only *execute* so many threads at the same time, you will need to redesign your approach.

You have an odd mixture of creating dedicated threads and uses of the TPL. I'd recommend using only the TPL for this solution.

Consider this much simpler code:

```
 var option = new ParallelOptions() {
  MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(numThreads.Value)
 };

 Parallel.For(0, Global.MyList.Count, option, i=> {
  Debug.WriteLine("Start signal from thread", i.ToString());
   var account = Global.MyList[i];
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
   Debug.WriteLine("End signal from thread", i.ToString());  
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what im looking for :)... i added this inside a task to avoid block UI

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your code is working as expected.

The lambda in your `Parallel.ForEach` does not contain any code that actually wait for the `t` thread to end. So it is dutifully starting each thread using the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` you've given but because it doesn't wait for the threads to finish it looks like it is starting them all at once.

Here's a true example of how `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` can work.

```
Action<int> action = i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting action {i}");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Ending action {i}");
};

var option = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
};

Parallel.For(0, 10, option, action);
```

That gave me:

```
Starting action 0
Starting action 5
Ending action 0
Starting action 1
Ending action 5
Starting action 6
Ending action 1
Starting action 2
Ending action 6
Starting action 7
Ending action 2
Starting action 3
Ending action 7
Starting action 8
Ending action 3
Starting action 4
Ending action 8
Starting action 9
Ending action 4
Ending action 9
```